# WebApi returning serialized HttpResponseMessage instead of text/html

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I can't for the life of me figure this out because if I start a fresh WebApi project this works just fine.  But in my existing application, it isn't working the same way. I'm dynamically building HTML and returning.  Code is below:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
Content = new StringContent(some html goes here)
};
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
return response;
```

The response from that code is (200 OK):

```
{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": [
                    "text/html"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Some of the configuration that might be relevant:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

The request is configured to accept the standard content types.

I've read some things about creating a custom formatter but I think that isn't necessary seeing that I'm able to return HTML just fine in a blank Web API project.  I'm thinking something with the middleware or something else in the pipeline is intercepting the object and serializing.

- .NET 4.6
- NuGet Packges: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.* are set to 5.2.5.
- This is an issue I'm experiencing in my local environment.

As always, any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the return type of your web API method?

Comment: HttpResponseMessage